# My Android 12 can resolve hostnames but can't connect directly to IP adress?

Tags: mobile-network, dns

I'm facing a weird behavior when using mobile data.
My Sony Xperia 5 mark II on Android 12 with Magisk root can connect to the Internet if I connect to the URL. However if I try to connect directly to the IP address, it doesn't work (network unreachable according to my web browser).

This seems to be system-wide:
For instance I can `ping google.com` but I can't `ping 8.8.8.8` (or whatever IP is behind google.com).
I can also connect to my own VPN server using Wireguard if I set the "host server" with my own .fr domain but not with my VPN server's IP.

I don't unterstand at all this issue. I tried cleaning arp table, DNS cache,...
When I disable Magisk the issue isn't solved either.
I don't especially know when it started...

Do you have any clue ?
Thanks

Comment: [IPv6](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#addresses)

Comment: What error does `ping` show? Did you check routing table?

Answer (score 1):

Okay problem solved.
Default APN for my carrier (Orange France) was uneditable and allowed only IPV6 connection.
Orange's APN settings shown on their site mentioned IPV4 only which wasn't working at all.
Adding an APN with IPV4/IPV6 stacking is the way to go.
Thanks for your help.